# Python, How to extend Decimal class to add helpful methods

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to extend the Decimal class to add some helpful methods to it, specially for handling money.

The problem when I go do this:

```
from decimal import Decimal
class NewDecimal(Decimal):
    def new_str(self):
        return "${}".format(self)

d1 = NewDecimal(1)
print d1.new_str() # prints '$1'

d2 = NewDecimal(2)
d3 = NewDecimal(3)
d5 = d2 + d3
print d5.new_str()   #exception happens here
```

It throws an exception:

```
AttributeError: 'Decimal' object has no attribute 'new_str'
```

This is because of the way Decimal does arithmetic, it always returns a new Decimal object, by literally calling Decimal(*new value*) at the end of the computation.
Does anyone no a workaround for this other than completely reimplementing all the arithmetic?

Comment: The usual solution is to just write functions that operate on `Decimal`s instead of trying to make them methods. (You could try monkey-patching the `Decimal` class, but that can be dangerous and confusing.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably don't actually want to do this just to have an extra method for printing Decimal objects in an alternate way. A top-level function or monkeypatched method is a whole lot simpler, and cleaner. Or, alternatively, a `Money` class that has a `Decimal` member that it delegates arithmetic to.

But what you want is doable.

---

To make `NewDecimal(1) + NewDecimal(2)` return `NewDecimal(3)`, you can just override `__add__`:

```
def __add__(self, rhs):
    return NewDecimal(super().__add__(rhs))
```

And of course you'll want to override `__iadd__` as well. And don't forget `mul` and all the other [numeric special methods](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

But that still won't help for `Decimal(2) + NewDecimal(3)`. To make that work, you need to define `NewDecimal.__radd__`. You also need to ensure that `NewDecimal.__radd__` will get called instead of `Decimal.__add__`, but when you're using inheritance, that's easy, because Python has a rule specifically to make this easy:

> *Note:* If the right operand’s type is a subclass of the left operand’s type and that subclass provides the reflected method for the operation, this method will be called before the left operand’s non-reflected method. This behavior allows subclasses to override their ancestors’ operations.

---

You may want to read the section [Implementing the arithmetic operations](http://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#implementing-the-arithmetic-operations) in the `numbers` module docs, and [the implementation of `fractions.Fraction`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/fractions.py) (which was intended to serve as sample code for creating new numeric types, which is why the docs link directly to the source). Your life is easier than `Fraction`'s because you can effectively fall back to `Decimal` for every operation and then convert (since `NewDecimal` doesn't have any different numeric behavior from `Decimal`), but it's worth seeing all the issues, and understanding which ones are and aren't relevant and why.

Answer (score 1):

The quick way to what you want, would be like this:

```
from decimal import Decimal
class NewDecimal(Decimal):
    def __str__(self):  
        return "${}".format(self)

    def __add__(self,b):
        return NewDecimal( Decimal.__add__(self,b) )


d1 = NewDecimal(1)
print d1 # prints '$1'

d2 = NewDecimal(2)
d3 = NewDecimal(3)
d5 = d2 + d3
print d5

> $5
```

Comment: This works up to a point; `d2 + Decimal(3)` returns a `NewDecimal`, but `Decimal(3) + d2` return an ordinary `Decimal`.

Comment: Because when you do 'Decimal(3) + d2', you call the Decimal.__add__ function... Not sure if there is anything you can do about it..

Comment: Sure there is. That's what `__radd__` is for.